# How to compute mean square error with a mixture of 2 normals?

Tags: r, mixture-distribution, mse

There generated data from mixture of two normals

```
x <- sort(c(rnorm(250,mean=-2,sd=0.5), rnorm(250,mean=3,sd=1.5)))
```

So the true density is

```
0.5*dnorm(x,mean=-2,sd=0.5) + 0.5*dnorm(x,mean=3,sd=1.5)
```

And there computed density of this data using kernel estimator

```
density(x)
```

How to correctly compute the MSE?